# Django 1.5 session variable not showing after Post-Redirect-Get

Tags: python, django, session

Using Django 1.5.1, I have sessions enabled in `INSTALLED_APPS` as well as `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`

I have a `django.views.generic.edit.CreateView` which is responsible for creating a new user on registration. That part works just fine. It also sends the new user an email to activate their account. That also works fine.

After the form is submitted and the form is determined to be valid, the user is redirected to a success url. On that success url page, I want to inform them that an email has been sent to their email address, e.g. "An email has been sent to foo@bar.com"

I'm been using `self.request.session['email'] = user.email` in the form view prior to the redirect generation. Locally (which uses a sqlite DB backend), this works perfectly. When the redirect loads, I see "An email has been sent to foo@bar.com".

However, when I deploy this to my staging server, I see "An email has been sent to ." If I manually refresh that page, then it displays the email correctly. The DB backend on my staging server is MySQL.

```py
def form_valid(self, form):
    user = form.save()
    self.request.session['email'] = user.email
    self.send_notification(user)
    return super(AccountCreateFormView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Edit:

In the template, I have the following:

```
An email has been sent to {{ request.session.email }}.
```

Comment: Other session-based machinery works fine on the production? I.E django admin, can you login there?

Comment: `form_valid` actually saves the form in the parent class if you are subclassing `CreateView` directly, so you can do `self.request.session['email'] = form.instance.email` and remove your `user` object. I know it doesn't help much with your question though...

Comment: I can log into the django admin area as well as my custom client area.

Comment: That's really good to know Ngenator, thanks!

Comment: I guess you can't though if `send_notification` is expecting a `User` object. Eh, I always miss little things like that lol...

Comment: I can just save the result of the super call, and then call `send_notification(self.object)`

Comment: That should work as well :P

Answer (score 1):

After spending a day on this problem, I've discovered the solution:

I upgraded from uWSGI  **1.0.2.1** to **1.9.8**.

I verified that going back to 1.0.2.1 caused the problem to resurface. I don't have an explanation as to WHY this is the case, but nonetheless, being on the latest uWSGI probably isn't a bad idea anyway.

---

Further investigation revealed that the problem I was experiencing was occurring in other areas. For example:

In the admin area, I would change an user from being active to inactive and then save the form, redirecting me back to the list of users. After clicking on the same user that I just deactivated, the check box would appear checked. Refreshing the page would reveal that "Active" was no longer checked.

Here's the part you might not expect: **A second refresh of the page would cause Active to appear checked!**

I was seeing this same behavior with my own forms as well. So I created a simple template that only contained `request.user.first_name` and `{% now "U u" %}`. The timestamp's purpose was to determine whether the rendered template was being cached or not.

In one tab, I updated the user's first name. In another tab, I quickly refreshed the new template. This caused it to **alternate** between the **new** value and the **old** value. The timestamp incremented correctly, no caching.

I thought maybe it was my browser (firefox). I opened chrome in incognito mode. In chrome, I opened the new template. In firefox, I submitted the form to change the user name. Back in chrome, I started to refresh quickly. Same exact behavior.

Jumping into dbshell and hitting the mysql db directly always gave me the correct value, no alternating.

In an attempt to rule some things out, I tried the following:

- Set the default `CACHES` backend to DummyCache (did not work)
- Set `CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_ANONYMOUS_ONLY` to True
- Installed `django-debug-toolbar` to look at the SQL directly. Refreshing the toolbar's sql quickly caused it to alternate values too!

I only started observing this issue after I had upgraded to django 1.5.1. Previously I was on django 1.4.2.

In sum, I propose that this be called the **django/uwsgi uncertainty principle**.